# Add a Class to a label with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to add the class `error` to a `<label>` with the `name` attribute set to `choice_16_0`. The code I wrote to do this, however, changes every label on the page to `<label for="choice_16_0" class="error">`, instead of just adding the new `class` to the label that already contains `for="choice_16_0"`.

Here's my code:

```
    if (!$("input[@name=\"choice_16_0\"]:checked").val()) {
        $("label").attr("for","choice_16_0").addClass("error");
    };
```

What's wrong with this, and how  can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selector `$("label")` is what's selecting every label on the page, change it to `$("label[name=choice_16_0")` to have it select the single label with the name you want.

Comment: Wow, not sure how I missed that when I caught it for the if statement. Thanks.

Comment: It happens, that's what reviews are for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var field = $("input[@name=\"choice_16_0\"]:checked");


 if (!$(field).val()) {
    $(field).attr("for","choice_16_0").addClass("error");
    error = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, `.attr(attribute, value)` is a setter while `.attr(atribute)` is a getter. You should use selectors instead: `$("label[for=choice_16_0]").addClass("error")`